# Definition of Compatible Charts in Loring Tu

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Loring Tu gives the following definition of compatible charts in his book *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Second Edition, page no. 49).

> **Definition 5.5.** Two charts $(U, \phi:U \to \mathbb{R}^n)$, $(V, \psi:V \to \mathbb{R}^n)$ of a topological manifold are $C^{\infty}$-*compatible* if the to maps $$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}: \psi(U \cap V) \to \phi(U \cap V), \quad \psi \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap V) \to \psi(U \cap V)  $$ are $C^{\infty}$. These two maps are called the *transition functions* between the charts. If $U\cap V$  is empty, then the two charts automatically $C^{\infty}$-compatible.

**My Question**

1. Which definition of smoothness is used for these transition functions?

   I am asking this because smooth functions between two manifolds are defined in terms of infinite differentiability in the latter part of the book.
2. Why are the two charts automatically $C^{\infty}$-compatible, if $U\cap V$  is empty?

Comment: The transition functions are maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or open sets thereof). Are you familiar with the definition of a smooth function in that setting?

Comment: it is based in smoothness in the usual sense between Euclidean spaces. If $U\cap V$ is empty then, by convention, we says that the transition map is smooth

Comment: @Masacroso Much appreciated.

Comment: @Masacroso You should give an official answer. By the way, I do not think that we need any convention if $U \cap V$ is empty. A map $f : A \to B$ between open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ is smooth if it has continuous partial derivatives of all order at all points of $A$. If $A$ is empty, this is trivially satisfied.